# Flink WindowFunction Fold

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I create a sliding window and hope to recursively pack all the elements enter that window period,
This is chunk of the code

```
.map(x => ((x.pickup.get.latitude, x.pickup.get.longitude), (x.dropoff.get.latitude, x.dropoff.get.longitude)))
        .windowAll(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(10), Time.minutes(1)))
        .fold(List[((Double, Double), (Double, Double))]) {(acc, v) => acc :+ ((v._1._1, v._1._2), (v._2._1, v._2._2))}
```

I hope to create a `List` in which the elements are `tuple`, but this does not work.

I tried this and it works:

```
val l2 : List[((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] = List(((1, 1), (2, 2)))
val newl2 = l2 :+ ((3, 3), (4, 4))
```

How can I do this?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the `fold` function needs to be the initial value and not the type. Changing the last line into:

```
.fold(List.empty[((Long, Long), (Long, Long))]) {(acc, v) => acc :+ ((v._1._1, v._1._2), (v._2._1, v._2._2))}
```

should do the trick.